# Protocols and Extensions swift

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and learning swift from "The Swift Programming Language(Swift 3 beta)". Below is a simple example from their book of protocol extension

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {

    var simpleDescription: String {get}

    mutating func adjust()
}

class SimpleClass: ExampleProtocol {

    var simpleDescription: String = "A vert simple class."

    var anotherProperty: Int = 69105

    func adjust() {

        simpleDescription += "Now 100% adjusted."
    }

}

var a = SimpleClass()

a.adjust()

let aDescripition = a.simpleDescription

struct SimpleStructure: ExampleProtocol {

    var simpleDescription: String = "A simple structure"

    mutating func adjust() {

        simpleDescription += "(adjusted)"
    }

}

var b = SimpleStructure()

b.adjust()

let bDescription = b.simpleDescription

extension Int: ExampleProtocol{

    var simpleDescription : String {

        return "The number \(self)"
    }

    mutating func adjust() {

        self += 42
    }
}

//var c = SimpleClass()
//c.adjust()
print(7.simpleDescription)
```

The end print result is "The number 7\n". As you can see that in extension, we have mutating function that add 42 to self. My question is that how can we call mutating function in extension so that result is added value of +42.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How we call mutating function in extension so that result is added value of +42.?

The function that results in the added value of +42 is the `adjust()` function of Int. To call it, just run this:

```
var c = 7
c.adjust()
print(c)
```

`c` is 49 (7 + 42)

Comment: But why you are not making class instance?

Comment: It's not necessary to call a class initializer, because this is an extension to Int

Comment: `c` is an instance of Int